# How to compute the residual of the nontrivial function at its essential singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I want to evaluate the following residue at its essential singularities $z \in I\pi\mathbb Z$,

$$\frac 1 {2\pi i} \oint dz \exp[i(-z+\coth z))].$$

I suppose what I can do is just perform Laurent expansion and correct the coefficient $a_{-1}$, but it just makes the situation worse because the integrand is composed function...

Is there any idea to help calculating such kind of residues?

Comment: Probably not. Why do you need it?

Comment: the only other idea I have is to consider $f(z)=\exp[i(-z+\coth z))]$ and consider $f'(z)=g(z)f(z)$ and then since $g$ is tractable so easy coefficients, look at identifying coefficients from the above which may give you a recurrence that is easier than approaching $f$ directly